# disappearing child <li>'s when position: 'fixed'

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement a 'sticky' navigation menu - a menu item that switches to a fixed position when the navigation bar reaches the top of the screen while scrolling.

This works a treat in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer (testing in 9), when the scroll reaches a certain point and the position switches to fixed, all the child `<li>`'s disappear (but the `<ul>` in which they are contained stay the same size.

I am trying to do this using jQuery (here is the code I have):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
        var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#navigation').offset().top;

        // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
        var sticky_navigation = function(){
            var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

            // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
            if ((scroll_top + 40) > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
                $('#navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':40, 'left':0 });
            } else {
                $('#navigation').css({ 'position': 'static', 'margin-top': 0 }); 
            }
        };

        // run our function on load
        sticky_navigation();

        // and run it again every time you scroll
        $(window).scroll(function() {
             sticky_navigation();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot demonstrate this as it is implemented on our secure website which requires login. Hopefully I have made sense. I can supply screenshots if necessary.

**EDIT**: I should mention, when the position is `static` the menu items display correctly in IE9. As I am scolling down and the menu becomes `fixed`, the menu items disappear!

**ANOTHER EDIT**: My first go of jsfiddle.net so hope it works http://jsfiddle.net/ecm5L/

Comment: Could you not make a fiddle which shows the issue? You're unlikely to get help if you're forcing people to recreate the problem themselves

Comment: if you could show the mark up off the menu also would really help

Comment: All mark up now shown in the link provided.

Comment: what about ie7 and 8. Is it working fine.

Comment: Don't know - jsFiddle doesn't seem to work with IETester. I haven't got IE7 and IE8 installed natively on my machine.

Comment: You can make IE9 operate in IE8 or IE7 mode by using the Developer Tools (press F12). Also `sticky_navigation_offset_top` is always 0 for me. Do you want a menu that starts at `40px` from the top but then if you have a long page and start scrolling the menu moves up to the top of the page and is then fixed?

Comment: Thanks for the IE tip. I have another bar at the top of the page for log out, help, faq, language links which is 40px high, so I want to menu just underneath.

Comment: In the fiddle, there isn't enough content to force a scroll bar to appear. A demo should be able to demonstrate the exact problem really. The problem I have is that I can't see the menu sticking at all, even if I add some long content. It might be best if you just adapt an existing solution to suit your needs. Maybe http://www.jay-han.com/2011/11/10/simple-smart-sticky-navigation-bar-with-jquery/

Comment: @andyb I already put in a load of 'lorum ipsum' in there to pad it out but the scroll bars don't appear so I didn't bother saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Gareth there is no issues with your js code but having issues with css filter property just replace this or try to remove the filter code to your #navigation css class:

this is yours:

```
#navigation {
    width:100%;
    height:48px;
    background: #27b4ec;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%, #27b4ec 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#37c6ff), color-stop(100%,#27b4ec)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 

  //*****REMOVE THIS******>
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#37c6ff', endColorstr='#27b4ec',GradientType=0 );
  //*****REMOVE THIS******>

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    min-width:1100px;
    z-index:10000;
 }

OR PASTE IT:

#navigation {
width:100%;
height:48px;
background: #27b4ec;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%, #27b4ec 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#37c6ff), color-stop(100%,#27b4ec)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #37c6ff 0%,#27b4ec 100%); 
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-o-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
margin-bottom:10px;
min-width:1100px;
z-index:10000;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that I spent hours looking into that and it was just the filter! Thanks very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it seems to be a bug that occurs when there is too much going on inside the page for your computer specs to handle it properly given that the browser is acting in the middle to render it, I was able to fix it by adding the following transform code to the fixed position element, (`transform: translateZ(0);-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`) that forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions. But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); will kick the GPU into action for the CSS transitions, making them smoother (higher FPS).

**Note:** translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x,y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration.

```
ul > li {
    position: fixed;
    /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* seems to do the same in Safari Family of Browsers*/
}
```